# Message preview is different depending on LinkedIn profile

Tags: linkedin-api

My company uses [LinkedIn Share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) to publish messages on LinkedIn profiles sharing content from WordPress posts.

One thing that is driving me crazy right now is that when I share the same URL and content to two different profiles, the preview cards that result from that are different. On one profile I got a full image preview like the following:

[image: Full Image Preview]

But the same content (same API params to share) produce this different preview:

[image: Reduced Preview]

I'm trying everything I can to get a consistent behavior. I'd like to have all previews being full size previews like the one shown in the first screenshot. API documentation doesn't help much here.

Any help or clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a random behaviour from LinkedIn. From time to time a significant percentage of accounts reached via the post API return a small thumbnail as well as a different content link (if you use redirected links like bit.ly). It happened for a week in February and since last Friday, including a number of Internal Server Errors. It looks like LinkedIn runs different code on different parts of its infrastructure.

So there is nothing you can do programmatically on your end I'm afraid.

Comment: We're also suffering the Internal Server Errors. It's a really frustrating situation...